# Do the resistors fail to distribute voltage?

Tags: pcb, resistors

I am working on infrared array PCB designed to track line i was supposed to get analog output (1 in the diagram) instead i get all 5 volts from all sensors in my PCB. I bought a infrared sensor [TCRT5000 Reflective Optical Sensor with Transistor Output"](https://www.vishay.com/optical-sensors/list/product-83760/) from this link. I am not able to debug it.

The circuit:-

[image: Schematic]

TX+ > Anode

TX- > Cathode

RX+ > Emitter

RX- > Collector

Every thing is connected correctly but I get a voltage on the transmitter of the sensor of 5 volts instead of being distributed on the 330 Ω resistor and the LED, and the same on the receiver instead of analog output.

My question is whether the resistor may be defective, or the sensor itself, knowing that they are all new?

Comment: We cannot help if we know nothing about the transmitter-receiver.

Comment: It seems like the LED may be backwards. The diagram does not seem to show what you are describing.

Comment: *is the resistor may be defected* Probably not but even the cheapest multimeters can measure resistance so get one of those and measure your resistors.

Comment: ok done i measured them they have 330 ohms and 10k as expected but i can't seem to figure out why the volt isn't distributed, what other possibilities for the resistor to have 0 volts and the LED 5v

Comment: when i put LED parallel to the transmitter it actually worked and i measured the volt on them approximately 1.8 for the LED-Transmitter and resistor

Comment: What do you mean by "distribute voltage"?

Comment: @Hearth I think he means "drop the excess voltage from the supply so the LED doesn't fry"

Comment: @Toor yes i mean that ,is there any reasons why this happens any ideas?

Comment: Which connections does TX+, TX-. RX+, and RX- correspond to with the pin names of the component in the datasheet (Collector, Emitter, Anode, Cathode)?

Comment: TX+ : Anode. TX-.: Cathode. RX+ Emitter: RX- Collector

Comment: The transistor emitter should be grounded, and the collector connected through a resistor to the positive supply.  The collector terminal will be the signal output, pulled to ground when IR light is detected.

Comment: @RawanYounis Those connections should be correct. Are you sure you did not miswire something or have a bad connection? Do you have more than one of these components? It is very unlikely that your resistor failed and extremely simple to check if it did. Furthermore, semiconductors in general, including LEDs tend to fail short, but your tests show that the LED is acting as an open-circuit which is very unlikley too. It is far more likely you connected it backwards. Is the place you bought your part from reputable?

Comment: i am connecting 5 of these IR senors on the same board on of them which have the same connection as the other is working while the others are not

Comment: i also tried this connection on a breadboard it worked with the sensor

Comment: if i am connecting 5 IR sensors they should be connected in series or parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the polarity of the diode and double check the pins

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhPeZ3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT:

[image]

Source: https://www.vishay.com/docs/83760/tcrt5000.pdf

Check the pinout of the device, if the photo transistor is 'on' then the 10k resistor should measure near 0V.

The C pin of the transistor side should be connected to the 10K resistor. The E pin connected to ground.

The A pin of the LED should be connected to the 330 Ohm LED and the C pin of the LED connected to ground. The forward voltage on the LED should be around 1V to 1.25V. Across the resistor it should be 3.75V to 3V

Comment: i have checked the polarity and it is not the problem, and this schematic is really helpful but i am not using diodes they are LED "transmitter" and receiver of the infrared , in order to track line and stuff  how can i get those on Circuit lab?

Comment: if i have circuit constits of LED - resistor 330 ohm - power supply 5 v , if i read the voltage on the two legs of the LED i should get 3.3 v is that correct? if so i am getting voltage on the two legs of the LED  5 v and on the two legs of the resistor 0 v

Comment: this is the sensor i am using , but the output is different from expected. The forward voltage on the LED is 5V. Across the resistor it is 0

Comment: Use a multi meter and take the device out of circuit, by using the meter in diode mode, measure the forward voltage across the diode, If it is not around 1 to 1.5V then it has probably been damaged

Comment: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/diodes/real-diode-characteristics

Comment: the LED on diode mode gave me 1.5 yet the voltage on it is 5v and it is not working

Comment: Do you have this in a breadboard?

Comment: it is on pcb , but i have one extra i tried it

Comment: Do a continuity check on the circuit

Comment: already done it everything is connected

Comment: Do a continuity check on a blank PCB, make sure it matches the schematics and the board file

Comment: just one more question if i am connecting 5 IR sensors they should be connected in series or parallel

Comment: It would be difficult to run these in series, parallel is the best way